# Trouble inserting data into database

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some issues getting my database to insert data from a form into my database.  I'm getting an ENCAPSED STRING error, but I can't seem to find said error.  Can anyone show me where the string is erroring out?

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `$user_table`(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role "', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
```

**CHANGES**

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO '" .$user_table ."'(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role ."', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
```

Now I'm no longer getting the error(thanks everyone), but the data isn't being entered into the database and I'm not getting any error.  Here's the complete script.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
        $p_num = $_POST["p_number"];
        $first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
        $last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $password = $_POST["pw"];
        $verify_password = $_POST["pw_verify"];
        $program = $_POST["program"];
        $role = $_POST["role"];
        $logged_in = 0;
        $registered = 0;

        $query = "SELECT * FROM `$user_table` WHERE `user_id` = '$p_num'";
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $user_id = "{$row['user_id']}";

            if($user_id == $p_num){
                echo "User already exists.";
            }
            else{
                $registered = 1;
                $insert = "INSERT INTO '" .$user_table ."'(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role ."', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
                $success = mysqli_query($connect, $insert);
                if($success){
                    echo "Done";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Error";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: '" .$p_num ."' must used without quotes because it's user id

Comment: $user_table should be ".$user_table."

Comment: At this point in time, I'm just trying to get the script to work.

Comment: can you add table structure with columns type ?

Comment: Um, no.  Why do you need the table structure and column types?

Comment: @Robert because you send integer values `$logged_in = 0; $registered = 0;` in quotes `, '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."'` and i am not sure that `logged_in`, `registered` has type string

Comment: Buddy, you're asking about `$p_num`, not once did you mention `$logged_in` or `$registered`.  Just because I named a variable a certain way and set it to a field called user_id, does not mean it's a number.

Comment: None of the given solutions are working.  However, I actually figured it out myself.  The while loop was making the connection to the database and running the select statement.  When I moved the insert statement outside of the while loop, it began working.  So I'm assuming that there was conflict within that while loop.

Comment: You weren't any trouble, I appreciate the assistance you provided.  I'll actually provide my solution to show how I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, it's posted.  The conflict thing is interesting though, I'm not sure why it would have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, as the other answers are **wide** open to SQL injection, I'll toss an answer into the hat...Try something like this

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO `".$user_table."`(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$MySQLI = new mysqli($connect);

$Statement = $MySQLI->prepare($SQL);

$Statement->bind_param("sssssssss", $p_num, $first_name, $last_name, $password, $email, $program, $role, $logged_in, $registered);

$Statement->execute();

printf("Error: %s.\n", $Statement->error);
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured this out myself.  There was apparently conflict within the while loop since it was connecting based on the SELECT statement.  Here's the solution.

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `$user_table`(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role ."', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
$success = mysqli_query($connect, $insert);
if($success){
    $registered = 1;
    mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE `$user_table` SET `registered` = 1 WHERE `user_id` = '$p_num'");
    echo "Done";
}
else{
    $registered = 0;
    echo "This user already exists.";
}
```

And for the record, yes, I understand that this is vulnerable to SQL Injection, but this is something that is still being worked on(security issues included), it's not live, it's not in production.

Comment: It's almost the same, but my original syntax is correct(as is yours, I tested it), but as I said, the problem was because it was within that while loop.  There was nothing wrong with your answer, the problem was that I was still incorporating your answer into that while loop.  Not sure why you got down voted so much.

Comment: Yeah, I'm confused as well.  If you find anything, let me know.

Answer (score -1):

you should change this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `$user_table`(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role "', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
```

to this:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `".$user_table."`(`user_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `password`, `email`, `program`, `role`, `logged_in`, `registered`) VALUES('" .$p_num ."', '" .$first_name ."', '" .$last_name ."', '" .$password ."', '" .$email ."', '" .$program ."', '" .$role "', '" .$logged_in ."', '" .$registered ."')";
```

and also change this:

```
'" .$p_num ."'
```

for this (delete simple quotes):

```
". $p_num ."
```

Answer (score -1):

When you have bad time on writing error free SQL statement, just use PHPmyadmin to insert the data then copy SQL statement generated by phpmyadmin then Edit the values with your variables in YOUR php file.